# Manipulate the content of an email with gmail add on

Tags: gmail-api, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Hi I am trying to develop a plugin for gmail that will read emails and manipulate the content of the email when it is read within gmail.

More specifically I want to change certain words within the email message.

I've already developed a plugin that can retrieve the email message and manipulate the message as a string but I don't know how to redisplay it.

Is this possible to do? If so which API do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought you could change the content of an email once in Gmail other than to change labels etc.

One approach that might work would be to manipulate the email in the Gmail UI by using a Browser plug-in such as a Chrome Extension.